# onclick message handling on a webpage button

Tags: asp.net, events

I have a button on a webpage that has the following added programmatically to its “Attributes” property.

```
btnDeleteNode.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if(confirm('delete this node?')){}else{return false}");
```

This works fine but now I need to check to see if the user has selected a node in a tree before asking if they want to delete it. If a node isn’t selected I need to tell the user to select one. My question is, can I do this using the above method (I don’t know java script) or should I use a different approach ?

Comment: You could simplify that to `"return confirm('delete this node?');"`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag (using javascript) on selection of any node and check the flag here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag or use from Asp Validators